# Python, Tkinter: Get Text from Checkbutton when Checked

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working with the following code.  My goal is to get the text of a Checkbutton when it is checked, and append that text to a list.  I want to write the code dynamically, because the size of list 'x' may change.  Here's what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

global j
j = []

x = ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'list']

def chkbox_checked():
    j.append(c.cget("text"))

for i in x:

    c = Checkbutton(root, text=i, command=chkbox_checked)
    c.grid(sticky=W)

mainloop()

print j
```

My output so far for j has been:

```
['list', 'list', 'list', 'list', 'list'] #depending on how many Checkbuttons I select
```

I'm looking for an output that is like this:

```
['this', 'list'] #depending on the Checkbuttons that I select; this would be the output if I
#selected Checkbuttons "this" and "list".
```

I've experimented with the "variable" option in the Checkbutton, but I can't seem to connect the dots.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have a feeling it's relatively straightforward.  Thanks!

Comment: `global` at global scope is meaningless (same as `pass`). I suggest you remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable c in the for loop is reassigned every iteration. That's why it only prints the last element `list`.

One solution is to use lambda functions.

```
def chkbox_checked(text):
    return lambda : j.append(text)

for i in x:
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=i, command=chkbox_checked(i))
    c.grid(sticky=W)
```